# Bash: remove first line of file, create new file with prefix in new dir

Tags: bash, file-io

I have a bunch of files in a directory, *old_dir*. I want to:

1. remove the first line of each file (e.g. using "sed '1d'")
2. save the output as a new file with a prefix, *new_*, added to the original filename (e.g. using "{,new_}old_filename")
3. add these files to a different directory, *new_dir*, overwriting any conflicting filenames

How do I do this with a Bash script? Having trouble putting the pieces together.

Comment: What have you tried? It's very difficult to debug your code when you don't include it in your question!

Comment: This is quite possibly a one-line script assuming your requirements really are that simple. Have you tried anything for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

old_dir="/path/to/somewhere"
new_dir="/path/to/somewhere_else"
prefix="new_"

if [ ! -d "$old_dir" -o ! -d "$new_dir" ]; then
  echo "ERROR: We're missing a directory. Aborting." >&2
  exit 1
fi

for file in "$old_dir"/*; do
  tail +2 "$file" > "$new_dir"/"${prefix}${file##*/}"
done
```

The important parts of this are:

- The `for` loop, which allows you do to work on each `$file`.
- `tail +2` which is notation which should remove the first line of the file. If your `tail` does not support this, you can get the same result with `sed -e 1d`.
- `${file##*/}` which is functionally equivalent to `basename "$file"` but without spawning a child.

Really, none of this is bash-specific.  You could run this in `/bin/sh` in most operating systems.

Note that the code above is intended to explain a *process*.  Once you understand that process, you may be able to come up with faster, shorter strategies for achieving the same thing.  For example:

```
find "$old_dir" -depth 1 -type f -exec sh -c "tail +2 \"{}\" > \"$new_dir/$prefix\$(basename {})\"" \;
```

Note: I haven't tested this.  If you plan to use either of these solutions, do make sure you understand them before you try, so that you don't clobber your data by accident.